# opensuse leap 15 ditched php7-imap, where to get replacement?

Tags: php, opensuse

After upgrading from openSuSe Leap 42.3 to 15.0 PHP Software using php7-imap does not work any more since openSuSe ditched php7-imap [php7-imap extension missing since 7.2.3](https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1089061).

Apparently there are [not even community packages for the current 7.2.5 version](https://software.opensuse.org/package/php7-imap).

Can I find a working imap.so for openSuSe Leap 15.0 elsewhere?

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but what happens when you manually download and install the 42.3 version?  https://software.opensuse.org/package/php7-imap

Answer (score -1):

Why not just download the PHP source code and compile the imap extension yourself like I just did. You will need to install the php7-devel, libc-client, and ssl-devel, and imap-devel. FURTHER the imap libs are put in lib64 but the PHP src is looking for them in lib. So create symlinks. It seems to work just fine.